# Inheritance or Injecting in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, oop, nestjs

I create an large project with using Typescript and NestJS framework, I want to create this project in OOP architecture and I have a want important question about it. I want to create one, base service with commons function that will be use in almost every service in the project, and I have a two ways to using a common parts.

First is to create an abstract class with commons methods like below:

```
export abstract class BaseService {}
```

and inheritance this abstract class in the target service:

```
export class UserService extends BaseService {}
```

Thanks of this I can use all of the methods that exists in `BaseService` with using `this` keyword and creating an reference to the function.

But I have a second approach, with using Injecting service via constrcutor:

```
export class BaseService {}
```

and injecting via constructor:

```
export class UserService {
    constructor (
        private readonly baseService: BaseService
    ){}

    someMethod(): void {
         return baseService.getHelloWorld();
    }
}
```

In this way I can to create an reference stricte from injecting service.

And now i have a question. Which approach is better in the large project?

PS. I prefer to create an generic function based on `<T>` on methods instead of class

Comment: The general rule always was "prefer delegation over inheritance".

Comment: So when I should use inheritance and/or abstract class/

Comment: I agree with @WiktorZychla. answering your Q
> So when I should use inheritance and/or abstract class/

Ideally, never

Comment: Inheritance is a strict coupling. Something painful to refactor. Delegation is safer, given that you can declare the injected entity as abstract and only use actual concrete type at composition. The whole DI builds on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case delegation to an injected service is more appropriate. If you do this, you should probably rename `BaseService` to something that does not imply that it is a base class to be inherited by other service classes. I suggest `SharedService` or `CommonService`.

Delegation is better here because your design suggests that the `BaseService` and `UserService` do not have the same meaning and purpose but only have common operations. Reducing code duplication should not be the main justification for choosing inheritance.